# jQuery how to remove the undefined first element?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I want to store some values in jquery array. But the problem is it is automatically adding a first element-a blank element.I wrote a condition for removing the first element if it is empty. But it's not even getting in to the condition.

My code is

```
var Ids= [];

function delImg(newThis){
    $(newThis).parent().hide();
    var Id = $(newThis).siblings('.hidden').html();
    if (Ids[0] == '') {
       Ids.splice(0, Ids.length);
       alert('at least getting in to the condition!'); 
    }
    Ids.push(Id);
    alert(Ids);
    return Ids;
}
```

When tried to use trim() the entire page is not working. Currently i am getting a comma before my first valid element because of this "undefined" element.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> it is automatically adding a first element

It can't actually. The problem lies elsewhere. I suspect it is perhaps on this line:

```
var Id = $(newThis).siblings('.hidden').html();
```

During the first call to `delImg`, the first sibling with `hidden` class may not have any html content or is itself absent.

*As an aside*, you would want to re-consider this line. You are trying to get html content of which sibling? Your selector will match all sibling elements with `hidden` class and hence return a set. Your statement as is will return the content of first element only in this case. It would be better to be explicitly telling which sibling to extract:

```
var Id = $(newThis).siblings('.hidden').first().html();
```

Comment: @downvoter, again!! please do care to explain your reason of downvote. This will help me improve the quality of my answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your if statement to this:

```
 if (Ids[0] == undefined)
```